# WCF - have client check for service availability

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, disconnect

I have a client-server system, both sides written by me, and I would like to put the clients in an 'offline' state when the server disconnects/dies, and then automatically bring them back 'online' when the server is available again.

For the first part, I listen for channel faulted events and handle that by setting the client to offline. I then start calling a 'ping' service on the server (every 30 sec.) which just returns a bool if it is alive. Once it is alive the client gets the bool and switches back online.

This all works, the problem I am having is that when the client calls the ping service and the server is down, no response is sent (obviously) and eventually, after about 2mins I get an endpoint not found exception. By this time I have already tried 3-4 more pings and hence have 3-4 exceptions brewing.

My question is, how can I deal with the ping service more gracefully? Ideally I would like to periodically call a service that lets me know if it is online, and instantly lets me know if it is not.

Comment: did you tried it? any sample code? Maybe ServiceContract with ***Ping*** method and test availability for `database connection, active directory, FileSystem, Email, Ftp, SFtp, SMS API`, etc

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What about this:

- if you detect a server disconnect, enter a "Ping" mode
- in the "ping mode", you set the client's "sendTimeout" to something very short, e.g. something like 2 secs or so, since your call to the service's Ping method should be answered almost immediately
- once your "Ping" worked successfully, you again re-create the client proxy and set the client's "sendTimeout" back to the original value (default is 1 minute - depends on what makes sense for you, 15 seconds, 30 seconds - whatever)

That way, if you're in "Ping mode", you get your responses (or timeouts) quickly and you can detect the availability of the service quickly.

Comment: Thanks Marc, great idea this is what I have done. I had completely forgotten that one can edit binding timeouts on the fly like this.

Comment: How to detect server is disconnected?

Comment: @Ashutosh: if the server is disconnected, your call will fail with one of several possible errors ("not found" or "timeout" or othesr)

Comment: sample code about `1) How to detect server is disconnected? 2)  re-create the client proxy 3) set the client's "sendTimeout"`