# How to verify that a particular WCF service is running or not?

Tags: wcf

let's suppose my WCF service is deployed on ineternet then how can I verify at run time that if particular service is up or not?

let's say my service can be accessed through url:

http://ipaddress/URI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to have some kind of a "ping" function or something on your service - which would e.g. return some arbitrary text (possibly the version number of your service or something).

This will work ....

**But:** how does this really help you?? A split fraction of a second later, when another call comes in, the network could be clogged or a cable disconnected or something.

Such a "keep alive" or "ping" function doesn't really help much - in reality, when calling a service, you must **always** be prepared for it to fail. No matter how many times you check for the service to be alive beforehand - when you make your actual service call, it might still fail miserably. Be prepared for that and handle it properly!

Comment: Thanks Marc!! thru my expereince I also realize the same issue and handle cases where service fails to reply and give proper message at the client end.

Answer (score 5):

Check the below links:

- [WCF - have client check for service availability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1234427/wcf-have-client-check-for-service-availability)
- [How to check the availability of a net.tcp WCF service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/881754/how-to-check-the-availability-of-a-net-tcp-wcf-service)

Comment: Thanks slugster for the links it really helped me to explore the problem  and its possible solutions !!

Answer (score 0):

How about using the expected client of your service to call the WCF service pointing to the URL. If client is not available try using a generic testing tool like [SOAPUI](http://www.soapui.org/).