# how to detect WCF service shutdown or disconnect from client?

Tags: c#, wcf

I'm building a WCF service,after a client connects to this service,when the service disconnect, the client doesn't notice that, and it doesn't fire any action, i would like to close client form whenever the connection lost,so how would i detect WCF service disconnect or shutdown from client side.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A simple approach is the client will call a simple method in service called IsAlive() just returns true as described in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085220/pinging-wcf-services).

There is another way you could achieve this using the new **Discovery/Announcement** features that comes with WCF 4. Though I haven't tried but this feature helps you to make the service notify the client if it gets into offline/shutdown.

Here is an example [post](http://www.freddes.se/2010/05/16/announcement-and-discovery-in-wcf-4/).

You can google "WCF announement service" and you'll get some good reference materials.

Comment: yea I've used Discovery before .. but i don't think using discovery all connection live is a good idea.. because it searches for all servers ... and announcement wouldn't work if the connection lost (machine shutdown/cable unplugged) .. but i will check the IsAlive() thing and reply you .. thanks for your answer :)

Answer (score 3):

You should probably just set up a timer that will continually ping the server, and if the fails, fire an event that the service is no longer available.

This answer also has some good suggestions.

[WCF - have client check for service availability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1234427/wcf-have-client-check-for-service-availability)

Comment: cool, can you give an example of doing a ping to a wcf service?

Comment: Create an operation on your contract called `Ping` that is takes no parameters and returns a `bool` of `true`. There's your ping.